# How do I convert a double variable to an integer variable?

Tags: c#, int, double

I need to convert n to an integer.  I have tried `h = rnd.Next(0, Math.Floor(n))` while n is stored as a double.  The code I have in that spot right now is below.

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 k = rnd.Next(50, 250);

 int n = Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(300-k));

 h = rnd.Next(0, n);
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(n)`

Comment: are you aware of what `Random` will give you ?

Comment: Yes, but I need the calculation involving that random number to be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.Floor` returns a double because this method can return special values such as NaN and infinity. You need to cast to `int`: `(int)Math.Floor(3.14)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case, `Math.Sqrt` can only return a positive `double`, you could skip the call to `Math.Floor` and just cast the result of `Math.Sqrt` to an `int`, which will truncate the result:

```
int n = (int)Math.Sqrt(300-k);
```

Note that truncating the `double` to an `int` simply discards the fractional digits of the `double` and calling `Math.Floor` rounds the `double` towards negative infinity. In this case, since your result is always positive, they end up being the same, but if you were working with negative numbers the operations would yield different results.